# Given a list of numbers, find a subset that sum to any number in a range of numbers

Tags: arrays, dynamic, sum, subset

How could I go about making a method that returns true or false when given an array of either positive or negative integers and a value k such that some numbers in that array sum up to any number from 1 to k.

For example, given an array [-10,20,14,-3] and k=6, this would return true as 14+(-10) = 4 which is between 1 and 6.

I know this requires dynamic programming (as it must run in polynomial time) but I'm not exactly sure how to go about implement it so any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way is to sort the numbers then sum a smaller and smaller list until it works

Here's an answer in scala

```
def sumit(x : List[Int], k: Int ): List[Int] = x match { case x  => if(x.sum > k ) x else sumit(x.init, k)

The List must be presorted, ie call like this
val numbers=List(-9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2)
sumit( numbers.sorted.reverse, 16)
```

and in perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#



sub any_adds_to {
    my $target=shift;
    my $list=shift;
    my @sorted=sort {$a <=> $b} @$list;
    my $v=0;
    for (@sorted) {
        $v=$v+$_;
        last if $v>$target;
    }
    return $v>$target;
}

sub assert {
        $_[0] ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";
}

my %test_as_false=(18=>[3,2,4,2,6],
          255=>[32,33,34,35,35],
          1200=>[-1,1000,1,199]);
for my $val_to_find (keys %test_as_false) {
    print assert(not(any_adds_to($val_to_find, $test_as_false{$val_to_find})));
}

my %test_as_correct=(18,[2,4,6,8],
                     255,[65,66,67,68],
                     1200=>[1,1000,1,199]);

for my $val_to_find (keys %test_as_correct) {
    print assert((any_adds_to($val_to_find, $test_as_correct{$val_to_find})));
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  How do that find a subset that sum to be a number <= k?